# Apache rewrite rule with query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

i need to rewrite mydomain.com/something/?p=value to mydomain.com/something/?page=value

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/p=$ $1?page=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

but don't wok, can help me?

Comment: The documentation explains, that you can only access the query string of a request using a `RewriteCond`. It offers good examples, I am sure you will easily find your way around: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, I haven't tested it yet, written in mobile will test it in sometime, should work I believe.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?page=%1 [L,NE]
```

Comment: You need to remove the `QSA` flag to prevent the original query string being appended, ie. to become `page=<value>&p=<value>`. Otherwise, this looks like it should work. (+1) However, for some reason, the OP has just recently asked the same question over on ServerFault?! https://serverfault.com/questions/1039696/rewrite-rule-with-query-string-dont-work